# replicate a mysql table to another server without writing it

Tags: mysql, replication

How can I configure MySQL to replicate a table to another server without writing the table on the first server? Can I write binary log but not commit the changes to the local table?

EDIT
I want to automatically (not one time) export all data inserted to a table to another mysql server, but to improve performance, I don't want to write the data to the master server, I want to directly send it to another server.

Comment: if you want to copy just 1 time, export then import to the second server. or you want to sync 2 database as master and slave?

Comment: I want to have a table out of the master server, because that table is about stats, and the master server is critical.

Comment: which database management software r u using? any db management software should have import/export features, u can use that. (and pls clarify more in the question, more details pls)

Comment: I don't want to dump a table one time, it has to be at all days or at all hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through standard replication. Just use the [`BLACKHOLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) storage engine on the master server.